# Using Math.round to round to one decimal place?

Tags: java, decimal, rounding

I have these two variables

```
double num = 540.512
double sum = 1978.8
```

Then I did this expression

```
double total = Math.round((num/ sum * 100) * 10) / 10;
```

but I end up with 27.0.

In fact I have many other variables and when I use them in the expression I always get a 0 in the tenth's place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score 114):

Helpful method I created a while ago...

```
private static double round (double value, int precision) {
    int scale = (int) Math.pow(10, precision);
    return (double) Math.round(value * scale) / scale;
}
```

Comment: Works for me!
double pi = 3.14159265;
round(pi, 1) --> 3.1
round(pi, 4) --> 3.1416

Comment: @LeoDroidcoder Actually, the expected result for `round(16.46, 1);` is `16.5`

Answer (score 31):

try this

for example

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
df.format(55.544545);
```

output:

```
55.54
```

Comment: This works, but it is much slower than using Math.round(double a)

Comment: This won't round the number. It just truncates to two decimals.

Comment: This answer should be removed, as it does not address the actual question. This solution does not round.

Answer (score 26):

```
Double toBeTruncated = new Double("2.25");

Double truncatedDouble = new BigDecimal(toBeTruncated).setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).doubleValue();
```

it will return 2.3

Comment: BTW, you probably don't want a variable name with `truncated` in it, since that has a different connotation than `round`. How about `toBeRounded` and `roundedDouble`? I mention this, because my first thought in seeing your answer was "Why is he truncating, when rounding was asked for?"

Comment: This method has been deprecated. Simply replace `BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP` with `RoundingMode.HALF_UP`.

Answer (score 24):

The [`Math.round` method returns a `long`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)) (or an `int` if you pass in a `float`), and Java's integer division is the culprit.  Cast it back to a `double`, or use a `double` literal when dividing by `10`.  Either:

```
double total = (double) Math.round((num / sum * 100) * 10) / 10;
```

or

```
double total = Math.round((num / sum * 100) * 10) / 10.0;
```

Then you should get

```
27.3
```

Comment: 1+  Another option is not to do any rounding at all, but instead only round the String display of the number.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That's not rounding then, just cutting off precision no matter of the tendency.

Comment: @haywire: Actually, using methods like System.out.printf() or String.format() can take care of the rounding for you. It doesn't just cut off precision, see my answer.

Comment: @MicahStairs sure they can, but that does not seem what HovercraftFullOfEels meant

Comment: @haywire, sounds to me like exactly what was meant. What other interpretation is there of *round* the string display? He didn't say *truncate*, did he?

Comment: @haywire yap, my bad :) misunderstood it

Comment: Does `sum` refer to precision in your answer?

Answer (score 13):

If you need this and similar operations more often, it may be more convenient to find the right library instead of implementing it yourself.

Here are one-liners solving your question from Apache Commons Math using [Precision](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.5/org/apache/commons/math3/util/Precision.html), Colt using [Functions](http://dst.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/api/cern/jet/math/Functions.html), and Weka using [Utils](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/core/Utils.html#roundDouble(double,%20int)):

```
double value = 540.512 / 1978.8 * 100;
// Apache commons math
double rounded1 = Precision.round(value, 1);
double rounded2 = Precision.round(value, 1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
// Colt
double rounded3 = Functions.round(0.1).apply(value)
// Weka
double rounded4 = Utils.roundDouble(value, 1)
```

---

Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>colt</groupId>
    <artifactId>colt</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka</groupId>
    <artifactId>weka-stable</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Double number = new Double("5.25");
Double tDouble = 
  new BigDecimal(number).setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).doubleValue();
```

this will return 5.3

Comment: `BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP` is deprecated from Java 9+. Use `RoundingMode.HALF_UP` in preference.

Answer (score 5):

A neat alternative that is much more readable in my opinion, however, arguably a tad less efficient due to the conversions between double and String:

```
double num = 540.512;
double sum = 1978.8;

// NOTE: This does take care of rounding
String str = String.format("%.1f", (num/sum) * 100.0);
```

If you want the answer as a double, you could of course convert it back:

```
double ans = Double.parseDouble(str);
```

Comment: Conversion to and from String is much more than `a tad` less efficient. If the question really was about `display to one decimal digit` (and it might be, not clear), then you've got a great answer. But if that is not the desire, this isn't a good path. Stick to doing numeric operations on numbers, unless the desired result is a string.

Answer (score 5):

Your method is right, all you have to do is add a .0 after both the tens and it will fix your problem!

```
double example = Math.round((187/35) * 10.0) / 10.0;
```

The output would be:

```
5.3
```

Comment: I put the example up

Answer (score 4):

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(".#");
String result = decimalFormat.format(12.763);                // -->  12.7
```

Comment: Since the question is about rounding, shouldn't this show 12.8?

Comment: I think the question about rounding not truncating.  Answer should be 12.8