# Basic Java, passing data between methods

Tags: java

I am new to Java and trying to make a basic body mass calculator. 
My problem is I need to ask the questions, convert the measurements and then pass it to another method then display the results in a separate method.
 I've added my code below but keep getting a 1.0 returned as the answer each time.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calcBMI {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );

        System.out.print("Enter weight in pounds: ");
        double weightInPounds = keyboard.nextDouble();
        double weightInKg = (weightInPounds / 2.2);

        System.out.print("Enter height in inches: ");
        double heightInInches = keyboard.nextDouble();
        double heightInMeters = (heightInInches / 0.254);
        double resultBMI = 1;

        displayResults(resultBMI);
    }

    public static double bodyMassIndex(double weightInKg, double 
    heightInMeters)
    {
        double resultBMI = weightInKg / Math.pow(heightInMeters, 2) * 1.375;

        return resultBMI;
    }        

    public static void displayResults(double resultBMI)
    {

        System.out.printf("The calculated body mass index was: " + resultBMI);

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

---

Updated code, now getting; 
    Enter weight in pounds: 180
    Enter height in inches: 68
    The calculated body mass index was: 1.1415618118905313E-5
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calcBMI {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );

        System.out.print("Enter weight in pounds: ");
        double weightInPounds = keyboard.nextDouble();
        double weightInKg = (weightInPounds / 2.2);

        System.out.print("Enter height in inches: ");
        double heightInInches = keyboard.nextDouble();
        double heightInMeters = (heightInInches / 0.0254);


        displayResults(bodyMassIndex(weightInKg, heightInMeters));
    }

public static double bodyMassIndex(double weightInKg, double heightInMeters)
    { 
        return (weightInKg / Math.pow(heightInMeters, 2));
    }        

public static void displayResults(double resultBMI)
    {

        System.out.printf("The calculated body mass index was: " + resultBMI);

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: I also need to round the BMI result to 1 decimal place using the printf method... I've tried adding the code System.out.printf("The calculated body mass index was: %.1f" + resultBMI); but I get an error when doing so

Comment: Correct your calculation for height first. Then test the weight and height with `160 lb` and `70 inch`. You should get `BMI 23`. It will work.

Comment: Holy shit batman it works. Got any idea on how I can make that rounded to one decimal place?

Comment: Take a look here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186778/using-math-round-to-round-to-one-decimal-place

Comment: Haha I figured it out before I seen your link... System.out.printf("The calculated body mass index was " + "%.1f", + resultBMI);

Comment: @user3437460 - one more quick question if I need to have the displayResults method pull info from another method, how would I get main to call this? i'll add code bits if needed.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out, thanks all for the assistance =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get 1.0 because you hard coded it as such.

Change this:

```
double resultBMI = 1;
```

To:

```
double resultBMI = bodyMassIndex(weightInKG, heightInMeters);
```

---

By the way, you could also have returned BMI directly in the method and there is ***no need to multiply by 1.375 anymore*** since you are already supplying weight in KG:

```
public static double bodyMassIndex(double weightInKg, double heightInMeters)
{
    return (weightInKg / (heightInMeters*heightInMeters));
}
```

---

**Add on:**

Your conversion from inches to meters is wrong as well. It should be:

```
double heightInMeters = (heightInInches * 0.0254);
```

Comment: I made the changes however now I'm getting a value returned of;
The calculated body mass index was: 0.0011415618118905313, I should be getting somewhere between 10 and 30, as 18.5 to 24.9 is normal

Comment: @BradHillis That is because your conversion is wrong. 1 inch = 0.0254 m, not 0.254.

Comment: Made the correction now getting, The calculated body mass index was: 1.1415618118905313E-5

Comment: @BradHillis I just updated my solution. Did you calculate it as I did?

Comment: @BradHillis Like I said, you didn't calculate heightInMeters correctly. It should be `(heightIntInches * 0.0254)`. You are dividing it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the `bodyMassIndex` method in your code at all. Change

```
displayResults(resultBMI);
```

to

```
displayResults(bodyMassIndex(weightInKg, heightInMeters));
```

`resultBMI` equals **1**, so of course the output would always be :

```
"The calculated body mass index was: 1"
```

Full code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Enter weight in pounds: ");
    double weightInPounds = keyboard.nextDouble();
    double weightInKg = (weightInPounds / 2.2);

    System.out.print("Enter height in inches: ");
    double heightInInches = keyboard.nextDouble();
    double heightInMeters = (heightInInches / 0.254);        

    // You can get rid of the resultBMI variable
    displayResults(bodyMassIndex(weightInKg, heightInMeters));
}
```

Comment: you might want to make those float literals double literals... for precision and to prevent implicit casting, like this: `2.2d` and `0.254d`

Comment: Those already are double literals. For floating point numbers, double is the default in Java.

Comment: I made the changes however now I'm getting a value returned of; "The calculated body mass index was: 0.0011415618118905313," I should be getting somewhere between 10 and 30, as 18.5 to 24.9 is normal

Comment: The output depends on your input. What do you provide as input to the program ?

Comment: 180 weight, and 68 inches, I just type them in as 180, then 68